Quotient with non equivalence relation
In Lean4, Quot allows the relation r to be non-equivalence:
Quot definition
Is there an example where r is not an equivalence relation?

Every relation $R \subseteq A \times A$ on a $A$ is contained in the smallest equivalence relation $E_R \subseteq A \times A$ ($E_R$ is the intersection of all equivalence relations that contain $R$). Taking the quotient $A/R$ is the same as taking the quotient $A/E_R$.
So, in principle, one never has to take a quotient by an arbitrary (non-equivalence) realation $R$, because we could use $E_R$ instead. However, it is easier to allow $A/R$ for arbitrary $R$ in a proof assistant, because there are no side conditions. If we insisted that quotients must be formed by equivalence relations, then every time we write $A/R$ we would also have to provide a proof that $R$ is an equivalence relation.
As for concrete examples, here is one. We can form finite multisets by quotienting List A by the relation R : A → A → Prop, defined by:
inductive R (A : Type) : List A → List A → Prop where
| swap : ∀ x y zs, R _ (x :: y :: zs) (y :: x :: zs)
| cons : ∀ x ys zs, R _ ys zs → R _ (x :: ys) (x :: zs)

def Multiset (A : Type) := Quot (R A)

The relation R says we can swap the order of elements, i.e., multisets are like lists where the order does not matter. But notice that R is not an equivalence relation. For example, reflexivity fails as ¬ R [] []:
example {A : Type}: ¬ R A [] [] := by intro H ; cases H

